# How do I use another version of Php for an app served under a certain path with Apache?

Tags: php, debian, apache-2.4, web-server, php-fpm

I am on Debian Testing so **Php 7.4**  seems to be the current one. This is fine with me since most of my Apache served apps are fine however two of them are broken. One is Wallabag and the other one is InvoiceNinja

I followed some tutorials on being able to run **Php7.3**  and **7.4** side by side. I can enable **7.3** but that breaks all the **7.4** apps like Nextcloud 18.

This is the page I followed

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-debian-10

I think this would work if I was using subdomains for the apps but I do not, so for instance Wallabag is served like this

`https://DOMAIN/wallabag`

I have the following custom sites file (it normally requires this to run under a path) for Apache which has been working fine as long as I revert to 7.3 or 7.2.

```
Alias /wallabag "/var/www/html/wallabag/web/"
<Directory "/var/www/wallabag/web">
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                Options -MultiViews
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

############# UNCOMMENTING THESE DO NOT HELP
###     <FilesMatch \.php$>
###                SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
###        </FilesMatch>


</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/wallabag/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I also added the **necessary php7.3  lines** in the config above (while 7.4 is the active php in the system) but that does not seem to help me. It just makes **Apache** to use 7.3 for everything. I am not able to put those lines into proper config lines. Please see the commented lines above.

`uname -ra`

```
Linux 5.4.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1 (2020-02-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`apache2 -v`

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.43 (Debian)
Server built:   2020-03-31T06:02:12
```

`systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service`

```
php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-04-26 02:22:15 CDT; 3 days ago
```

`systemctl status php7.3-fpm.service`

```
php7.3-fpm.service - The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.3-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-29 10:43:23 CDT; 23min ago
```

`ls -alh /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock`

```
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Apr 29 10:43 /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock
```

Basically I want to be able to use 7.3 for some of the apps that are running under certain apths like `/wallabag`